# Resize ImageView background accordingly to Image size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to have the background of the image re-size accordingly to the Image size

I have a simple ImageView

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The `white_bg` is an xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

The Problem is that there are large white spaces between the image and the background.
The only thing appeared to solve the problem was setting the `ScaleType' attribute to FitXY but it stretches small images and they turn to be ugly.

I have also tried adding a `LinearLayout` parent to the `ImageView` with `wrap_content' width and height attributes but there were still large white spaces with some of the images.

Comment: I seriously don't understand what you are looking for, you want your images to be fullscreen but you also don't want them to stretch when they are smaller size? so what do you want? (it would help if you would show the picture from "current result" being a "desired result"

Comment: I dont mind if the image will be full screen, the only thing I want is the background to adjust to the size of the image, the second image is the desired result

Comment: try adding 'android:shape="rectangle"' attribute to the <shape> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

not sure but it helps you